# Programmatically link to Component with Props in React (Hooks)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I am trying to redirect to a component after clicking. I need to send it some state or props.

I can do this with a Link component; ie

```
<Link to={pathname: '/messages', state: { id: post.id}} ...
```

this redirects to the Component and I can get the state from location in the new component.

**However**, I need to perform some action on click first, so I can't (or don't know how to) programtically redirect with state/props.

I can use

```
.....

history = useHistory()
function func() 
{
     //send ajax request
     history.push()
}

....

<button onClick={func}....>Save Todo</button>
```

which will take me to the component, but I need to pass the id as well.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [useHistory](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory). Do history.push and provide an object with `pathname` and the `data` you need to pass on to the component to be redirected.

```js
...
history = useHistory()
const handleClick = () => {    
    apiService('myEndpoint')
        .then(response => {
           history.push({
             pathname: '/myPath',
             state: { id: response.data.id } // <----- send your id here
        });
    }
}
```

**In the receiving component:**

```js
    ...
    useEffect(() => {
       console.log(props.location.customNameData);
    }, []);
```

Note:
You can also use [useLocation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/uselocation)

```js
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
console.log(location.state.id);
```